# How would I be able to read a .geo file and extract a column of data from said file?

Tags: geopandas, geo

[image of my input code and the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEHQr.png) I've looked online to try and figure out how to read and extract from my .geo file, and when I tried to use geopandas I get this error message. I couldn't find anymore relevant information on the geopandas documentation.

```
CPLE_OpenFailedError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()

fiona/_err.pyx in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer()

CPLE_OpenFailedError: 'GAMMAA5.geo' not recognized as a supported file format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DriverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f48d02089e42> in <module>
----> 1 gpd.read_file('GAMMAA5.geo')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in _read_file(filename, bbox, mask, rows, engine, **kwargs)
    279             path_or_bytes = filename
    280 
--> 281         return _read_file_fiona(
    282             path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox=bbox, mask=mask, rows=rows, **kwargs
    283         )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in _read_file_fiona(path_or_bytes, from_bytes, bbox, mask, rows, where, **kwargs)
    320 
    321     with fiona_env():
--> 322         with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
    323             crs = features.crs_wkt
    324             # attempt to get EPSG code

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/env.py in wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    455 
    456         with env_ctor(session=session):
--> 457             return f(*args, **kwds)
    458 
    459     return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/_init_.py in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    290 
    291         if mode in ("a", "r"):
--> 292             colxn = Collection(
    293                 path,
    294                 mode,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fiona/collection.py in _init_(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, include_fields, wkt_version, allow_unsupported_drivers, **kwargs)
    241             if self.mode == "r":
    242                 self.session = Session()
--> 243                 self.session.start(self, **kwargs)
    244             elif self.mode in ("a", "w"):
    245                 self.session = WritingSession()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Session.start()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.gdal_open_vector()

DriverError: 'GAMMAA5.geo' not recognized as a supported file format.
```